# How can I specify in fortran compiler that declared variables shoud not be potentially treated as implicit function declaration

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I was pretty surprised that :

```
      subroutine test   (es, f)
!

      implicit none
!
      double precision es
      double precision f
      f=es(1,2)
!
      return
      end
```

compiled without any error or warning : `es` is not declared with `dimension`.
I understand that `es` is then considered as a function.

But when linking there is no error considering the missing symbol `es` !

Looking at the assembler `es(1,2)` corresponds to `call    rdx`, hence no link error.

To avoid this problem I can declare `es` as `double precision, intent(inout)` then I get :

> Error: PROCEDURE attribute conflicts with INTENT attribute in 'es' at

Which is what I was expecting the first time.

**Question**

Is there a compiler option (ifort or gfortran) to force the declared variables to be treated as `intent(inout)`and not as `procedure call` ?

Thank you in advance.

Ps: I have a legacy code and I do not want to add `intent(inout)` everywhere to detect this kind of misinterpretation.

Comment: In a hurry but -Wimplicit-interface might help in gfortran. But in old fashioned code you'll probably get swamped with information from other routines. The best fix is to supply an Intent

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Do you know any equivalent of -Wimplicit-interface for intel-fortran ?

Comment: @PilouPili -Wimplicit-interface will likely give you so many hits that you will fail to spot a single weird one among them. You should understand what it does. It does NOT what you asked for in the question, it will give you a warning for every single Fortran 77 style call in your programs. It may be hundreds, it may be thousands. I suggest you rather use error checking options the compilers have. Please see my answer. For Intel it would be `-warn interfaces` or just `-warn` to enable all warnings.

Answer (score 3):

*"But when linking there is no error considering the missing symbol es !"*

There is not supposed to be one. `es` is the name of the dummy argument, not the name of the actual procedure that you would pass there. What would actually happen in most implementations that the code would try to call the pointer to the variable as a function address and that would lead to some kind of error. Either executing non-executable code, or invalid instruction or executing a virus code carefully put to the right location of the stack or heap by an intruder.

*"Is there a compiler option (ifort or gfortran) to force the declared variables to be treated as intent(inout)and not as procedure call ?"*

No, and even if it were it would break the code semantics and that is a BAD THING(TM). Anyone using the code somewhere else or without the option would be screwed. Especially the point that it creates a possible dangerous code vulnerability is a clear reason to not allow such a thing.

---

It is better to say that explicitly,even though I believe you are aware of this and just want a diagnostic tool to warn you:

The correct declaration of an array involves its dimension, like

```
double precision es(1,*)
```

---

Also be aware that the compilers are able to check for similar errors when calling the procedure. Gfortran will find out when the calling code is in the same file, Intel  sometimes even if not (when `-warn interfaces` is enabled). Enabling link time optimizations may also help to find it. And of course, modern Fortran should use modules.

Consider:

```
      subroutine test   (es, f)
!

      implicit none
!
      double precision es
      double precision f
      f=es(1,2)
!
      return
      end

   double precision a(2,1), b   
   call test(a, b)
end
```

Because the call is in the same file, gfortran will automatically, without any additional option, identify the problem:

```
declaration.f90:14:13:

    call test(a, b)
             1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘es’ at (1) (scalar and rank-2) [-Wargument-mismatch]
```

Intel will require the warning flag

```
ifort -warn interfaces declaration.f90 
declaration.f90(14): error #6637: When a dummy argument is a function, the corresponding actual argument must also be a function.   [A]
   call test(a, b)
-------------^
compilation aborted for declaration.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: @francescalus The declaration basically gives it an implicit EXTERNAL attribute.  "The EXTERNAL attribute specifies that an entity is an external procedure, dummy procedure, procedure pointer,
or block data subprogram." Here it is a dummy procedure, not an external procedure.

Comment: Gah, all true.  Sorry for the distraction.  (I noted it was a dummy, then promptly forgot.)

Comment: @VladimirF thank you very much for your answer. I understood why there is no link error when looking at the assembler but thanks for confirming. I would love to accept the answer but "No, and even if it were it would break the code semantics and that is a BAD THING(TM).", as much as I understand, this answer is too disappointing.